# How to remove the / at the end of my url with 11ty

Tags: html, request, pug, vite, eleventy

I'm using vite, 11ty and pug to create a website and I'd like to have no / at the end of my url. I tried to do it for example with About page but it didn't work.

```
---
permalink: |
  | "/About"
---
```

About.pug is in view folder

http://localhost:3000/About/ didn't work
http://localhost:3000/About not recognize, so its the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define explicit file path

```yaml
permalink: '/About.html'
```